# How to create a modular select menu in python with discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have a dictionary with questions as keys and answers as values. I want to create a modular select menu using variables to be able to draw a random question and that the menu automatically has the right question and right answers given by the variables without having to make a select menu view class per question

```
Q1 = {"Aube ou crépuscule" : {
        "Aube" : {"gry" : 73, "serd" : 73, "pouf" : 30, "serp" : 26}, 
        "Crépuscule" : {"gry" : 27, "serd" : 27, "pouf" : 70, "serp" : 74}
        }, 
      "Forêt ou rivière" : {
        "Forêt" : {"gry" : 74, "serd" : 73, "pouf" : 26, "serp" : 28}, 
        "Rivière" : {"gry" : 26, "serd" : 27, "pouf" : 74, "serp" : 72}
        },
      "Etoiles ou lune" : {
        "Etoiles" : {"gry" : 27, "serd" : 74, "pouf" : 33, "serp" : 72}, 
        "Lune" : {"gry" : 73, "serd" : 26, "pouf" : 67, "serp" : 28}}}
```

i.e random question is Aube ou crépuscule and select menu show Aube and Crépuscule

I tried first:

```
async def select_callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, select: discord.ui.ChannelSelect):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Awesome! I like {select.values[0]} too!")

class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, interaction, question, choix):
        super().__init__()
        
        # Create the select menu
        select_menu = discord.ui.Select(
            custom_id="MySelect",
            placeholder=question,
            min_values=1,
            max_values=1,
            options=choix
        )
        select_menu.callback = select_callback(self, interaction, select_menu)
        self.add_item(select_menu)



@bot.tree.command()
async def que(ctx: discord.Interaction):
    numquestion = random.randint(0, len(Q1)-1)
    question = list(Q1.keys())[numquestion]
    lab1 = list(Q1[question].keys())[0]
    lab2 = list(Q1[question].keys())[1]
    choix = [
        discord.SelectOption(label = lab1),
        discord.SelectOption(label = lab2)
    ]
    my_view = MyView(ctx, question, choix)
    await ctx.response.send_message(question, view = my_view)
```

and get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bilbibalou\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 430, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable
```

and after I tried:

```
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, question, choix):
        super().__init__()
        
        @discord.ui.select(
            placeholder = question,
            min_values = 1,
            max_values = 1,
            options = choix
        )
        async def select_callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, select: discord.ui.ChannelSelect):
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"Awesome! I like {select.values[0]} too!")
```

there only the question of await ctx.response.send_message(question, view = my_view) is display not the select menu

Comment: I believe you would have to use some form of discord UI with that

Comment: yes I'm trying to figure out how to use it but I can't, that's why I'm posting here